# Benefits of using an autogenerated primary key instead of a constant unique name

Tags: sql, primary-key, auto-generate

I've heard that having an autogenerated primary key is a convention. However, I'm trying to understand its benefits in the following scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE countries 
(
    countryID int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    countryName varchar(128) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE students 
(
    studentID int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    studentName varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    countryOfOrigin int(11) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (countryOfOrigin) REFERENCES countries (countryID)
);

INSERT INTO countries (countryName)
VALUES ('Germany'), ('Sweden'), ('Italy'), ('China');
```

If I want to insert something into the students table, I need to lookup the `countryID`s in the countries table:

```
INSERT INTO students (studentName, countryOfOrigin)
VALUES ('Benjamin Schmidt', (SELECT countryID FROM countries WHERE countryName = 'Germany')),
       ('Erik Jakobsson', (SELECT countryID FROM countries WHERE countryName = 'Sweden')), 
       ('Manuel Verdi', (SELECT countryID FROM countries WHERE countryName = 'Italy')), 
       ('Min Lin', (SELECT countryID FROM countries WHERE countryName = 'China'));
```

In a different scenario, as I know that the countryNames in the countries table are unique and not null, I could to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE countries2 
(
    countryName varchar(128) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE students2 
(
    studentID int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    studentName varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    countryOfOrigin varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (countryOfOrigin) REFERENCES countries2 (countryName)
);

INSERT INTO countries2 (countryName)
VALUES ('Germany'), ('Sweden'), ('Italy'), ('China');
```

Now, inserting data into the students2 table is simpler:

```
INSERT INTO students2 (studentName, countryOfOrigin)
VALUES ('Benjamin Schmidt', 'Germany'), 
       ('Erik Jakobsson', 'Sweden'), 
       ('Manuel Verdi', 'Italy'), 
       ('Min Lin', 'China');
```

So why should the first option be the better one, given that countryNames are unique and are never going to change?

Answer (score 1):

There are two apects involved here:

- natural keys vs. surrogate keys
- autoincremented values

You are wondering why to have to deal with some arbitrary number for a country, when a country can be uniquely identified by its name. Well, imagine you use the country names in several tables to relate rows to each other. Then at some point you are told that you misspelled a country. You want to correct this, but have to do this in every table the country occurs in. In big databases you usually don't have cascading updates in order to avoid updates that unexpectedly take hours instead of mere minutes or seconds. So you must do this manually, but the foreign key constraints get in your way. You cannot change the parent table's key, because there are child tables using this, and you cannot change the key in the child tables first, because that key has to exist in the parent table. You'll have to work with a new row in the parent table and start from there. Quite some task. And even if you have no spelling issue, at some point someone might say "we need the official country names; you have China, but it must be the People's Republic of China instead" and again you must look up and change that contry in all those tables. And what about partial backups? A table gets totally messed up due to some programming error and must be replaced by last week's backup, because this is the best you have. But suddenly some keys don't match any more. You never want a table's key to change.

You say "country names are unique and are never going to change". Think again :-)

It is easier to have your database use a technical arbitrary ID instead. Then the country name only exists in the country table. And if that name must get changed, you change it just in that one place, and all relations stay intact. This, however, doesn't mean that natural keys are worse than technical IDs. They are not. But it's more difficult with them to set up a database correctly. In case of countries a good natural key would be a country ISO code, because this uniquely identifies a country and doesn't change. This would be my choice here.

With students it's the same. Students usually have a student number or student ID in real world, so you can simply use this number to uniquely identifiy a student in the database. But then, how do we get these unique student IDs? At a large university, two secretaries may want to enter new students at the same time. They ask the system what the last student's ID was. It was #11223, so they both want to issue #11224, which causes a conflict of course, because only one student can be given that number. In order to avoid this, DBMS offer sequences of which numbers are taken. Thus one of the secretaries pulls #11224 and the other #11225. Auto-incremented IDs work this way. Both secretaries enter their new student, the rows get inserted into the student table and result in the two different IDs that get reported back to the secretaries. This makes sequences and auto incrementing IDs a great and safe tool to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a short question though:
You wrote _Then at some point you are told that you misspelled a country.._ so if I misspell some `countryName` in `countries2` table - which is a parent table - then it has to be also misspelled in the child tables. Is it right to say that misspelling a country in a child table is impossible, given it is correct in the parent table?

Comment: Yes, if this is the key, then it is either misspelled in all tables or correctly spelled in all tables.

Answer (score 0):

Convention can be a useful guide. It isn't necessarily the best option in all situations.

There are usually tradeoffs involved, like space, convenience, etc.

While you showed one method of resolving / inserting the proper country key value, there's a slightly less wordy option supported by standard SQL (and many databases).

```
INSERT INTO students (studentName, countryOfOrigin)
WITH list (name, country) AS (
  SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES ('Benjamin Schmidt', 'Germany')
             , ('Erik Jakobsson', 'Sweden')
             , ('Manuel Verdi', 'Italy')
             , ('Min Lin', 'China')
         ) AS x
     )
SELECT name, countryID
  FROM list      AS l
  JOIN countries AS c
    ON c.countryName = l.country
;
```

and a little less wordy again:

```
INSERT INTO students (studentName, countryOfOrigin)
WITH list (name, country) AS (
        VALUES ('Benjamin Schmidt', 'Germany')
             , ('Erik Jakobsson', 'Sweden')
             , ('Manuel Verdi', 'Italy')
             , ('Min Lin', 'China')
     )
SELECT name, countryID
  FROM list      AS l
  JOIN countries AS c
    ON c.countryName = l.country
;
```

Here's a test case with MariaDB 10.5:

[Working test case (**updated**)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=776a30811c0461747ff32af56d1f8292)